# Separating records in same Database column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry about the title but the question is hard to sumarize. I am dealing with a poorly constructed database and came across a table that has multiple records on the same column, something like this:

```
| Column Header |

Record1; Record2; Record3
```

I wanted to ask if there is any way in SQL to separate those records using the `;` as a separator. I ask this because remaking the database isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: so, you mean to say that you want those records to be seperated in rows...right?

Comment: If its possible, it would be the ideal

Comment: which programming language you want to use this in?

Comment: This is asked almost daily on Stackoverflow and is a duplicate of so many questions... None however have answers quite as good as the answers provided by a series of articles by Aaron Bertrand – [Split strings the right way – or the next best way]( sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
, and [Splitting Strings : Now with less T-SQL](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql).

Comment: Thanks for the reading material!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @badData TABLE (id INT NOT NULL, txt NVARCHAR(max));

INSERT INTO @badData
VALUES (1, 'foo,bar,baz'), (2, NULL);;

-- the idea is to recursively 'pop' a value from the start of the string, splitting it into 'head' and 'tail' components
WITH unpacked (id, head, tail)
AS (
  SELECT id, LEFT(txt, CHARINDEX(',', txt + ',') - 1), STUFF(txt, 1, CHARINDEX(',', txt + ','), '')
  FROM @badData

  UNION ALL

  SELECT id, LEFT(tail, CHARINDEX(',', TAIL + ',') - 1), STUFF(tail, 1, CHARINDEX(',', tail+ ','), '')
  FROM unpacked
  WHERE tail > ''
  )
SELECT id, head
FROM unpacked
ORDER BY id
```

heavily plagiarised from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5493616/6722

Answer (score 1):

fast solution -

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Col NVARCHAR(2000),
    Col1 AS PARSENAME(REPLACE(Col, '; ', '.'), 3),
    Col2 AS PARSENAME(REPLACE(Col, '; ', '.'), 2),
    Col3 AS PARSENAME(REPLACE(Col, '; ', '.'), 1)
)

INSERT INTO @T (Col)
VALUES ('Record1; Record2; Record3')

SELECT * FROM @T
```

good solution - normalize table

Comment: Fairly strong caveats - limited to 3 delimiters and relies on none of the strings being split containing `.`.